# How to get previous row value of a text column in new column in Dax -Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In PowerBI, I'm trying to get a calculated column (not a measure) that gets preivous row value. I tried adding a column with DAX formula as below:

`DAX Index =  RANKX(ALL( InventoryItems ),InventoryItems[INVENTORYDATE],,ASC,Dense)`

`STATUSyesterday = VAR _CurrentRowIndex = InventoryItems[DAX Index] VAR _PreviousRowIndex = CALCULATE(MAX( InventoryItems[DAX Index] ),FILTER( InventoryItems, InventoryItems[DAX Index] <_CurrentRowIndex ),ALL( InventoryItems[DAX Index] ))VAR _Result = CALCULATE(MAX(InventoryItems[STATUSinventory] ),FILTER( InventoryItems, InventoryItems[DAX Index]=_PreviousRowIndex ))RETURN _Result`

Ideally, result of STATUSyesterday should first row blank and from second row onwards it should be STATUSinventory instead, its just 'out of stock' as it is occurring maximum time.

query image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works. What I am doing is getting the id for the previous row and the matching the "STATUSinventory" with the previous id.

```
Previous Row Value =
VAR _PreviousRow = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'InventoryItems'[DAX Index] ),
    ALL ( 'InventoryItems' ),
    'InventoryItems'[ITEMNUMBER]
        = EARLIER ( 'InventoryItems'[ITEMNUMBER] ),
    'Summary Table'[Date] < EARLIER ( 'InventoryItems'[INVENTORYDATE] )
)

RETURN 

CALCULATE (
LASTNONBLANK ( 'InventoryItems'[STATUSinventory], 1 ),
ALL ('InventoryItems' ),
'InventoryItems'[DAX Index] = _PreviousRow
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to add an index. You can use the Inventorydate to determine the order. Try something like this:

```
STATUSyesterday =
VAR currentInventoryDate = 'InventoryItems'[INVENTORYDATE]
VAR previousInventoryDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'InventoryItems'[INVENTORYDATE] ),
        ALL ( 'InventoryItems' ),
        'InventoryItems'[INVENTORYDATE] < currentInventoryDate
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'InventoryItems'[STATUSinventory] ),
        ALL ( 'InventoryItems' ),
        'InventoryItems'[INVENTORYDATE] = previousInventoryDate
    )
```

[currentInventoryDate] is the Inventorydate in the current row.

[previousInventoryDate] is the max(IventoryDate) that is smaller than the [currentInventoryDate].

The last CALCULATE returns the STATUSinventory of the previousInventoryDate.